# Why won't -moz-filter: blur(4px) work in firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have used the blur filter for chrome and it works fine, I try adding the moz filter so it can show in firefox and it doesn't blur?

The code for the image blur:

```
.img-wrap:hover img {

    filter: blur(4px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
    -moz-filter: blur(4px);
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Is anything reported in the Error Console? Is your selector valid? Have you tried `-moz-blur(4px)`?

Answer (score 2):

CSS filter effects [arent supported in Firefox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters), you will need to look into using [SVG blur effects](http://www.broken-links.com/2013/11/20/cross-browser-filters-css-svg/), there is a [tutorial here which may help:](http://css-plus.com/2010/05/how-to-add-a-gaussian-blur-effect-to-elements-within-firefox/)

HTML

```
<img src="yourImage.png" alt="" />
<svg:svg>
    <!-- Filter ID/Name -->
    <svg:filter id="blurFilter">
        <!-- Amount of Gaussian Blur that should be applied -->
        <svg:feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.9"/>
    </svg:filter>
</svg:svg>
```

CSS

```
img { filter:url(#blurFilter); }
```